# Which eclipse version to install for developing in Android (Aug 2012)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

This question is double, but no one asked it recently.
I want to use Eclipse for developing in Android and making webapps.
I used Indigo, but I see a lot of downloads on this page: http://eclipse.org/downloads/

Since my computer got stolen and I need to reïnstall everything, I thought, good time to ask.
Can anybody tell me which version is better to download and install?

And anybody any tips on the needed plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indigo is fine.

However, it might be in your best interest to download and install **Juno**. Juno's UI is slightly different than Indigo's, but it *is* the newest version of Eclipse (Juno is 4.x, whereas Indigo is 3.x).